# How do I access android:label for an Activity

Tags: android

Given

Android.xml:

```
<activity android:name='.IconListActivity'
  android:label='@string/icon_list_activity_name'
/>
```

Strings.xml:

```
<string name='icon_list_activity_name>Icon List</string>
```

How do I access to the string *'Icon List'* given *IconListActivity.class*?

Comment: Can you please give a use-case where you wish to do so? Maybe we can find a workaround.
Also, whether the IconListActivity.class is in same apk or not?

Comment: IconListActivity is an activity I'm writing while teaching myself Android programming.

Comment: why not just use `R.string.icon_list_activity_name` at the point where you need it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`PackageManager#getActivityInfo()` returns an `ActivityInfo` structure, which has a `labelRes` and a `name` field, one of which should have what you need.

Answer (score 10):

From any activity:

```
String label = null;
try {
    label = getResources().getString(
        getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), 0).labelRes);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Activity Label: " + label);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have the [ComponentName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html), then you can do the following:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ActivityInfo activityInfo = pm.getActivityInfo (componentName, 0);
Log.d ("ActivityLabel", activityInfo.loadLabel (pm).toString ());
```

Answer (score 3):

We have being trying to get the label but `labelRes` return `0` and `name` is the simple class name of the Activity.

The way we've managed to get the String from the label (we're targetting API 23, btw) was using the **nonLocalizedLabel** field:

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class);
ActivityInfo info = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(cn, 0);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "label == " + info.nonLocalizedLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for the activity element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), the `name` xml attribute is for an `Activity` subclass, i.e. it is *not* anything to do with the name of the activity. `labelRes` is the field wanted here (corresponding to the `label` XML attribute).