# Android - How to get application name? (Not package name)

Tags: android

In my manifest I have:

```
  <application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
```

How do I get the label element?

**Note: My code is running inside of someone else's, so I don't have access to @string/app_name**

Answer (score 209):

There's an easier way than the other answers that doesn't require you to name the resource explicitly or worry about exceptions with package names. It also works if you have used a string directly instead of a resource.

Just do:

```
public static String getApplicationName(Context context) {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();
    int stringId = applicationInfo.labelRes;
    return stringId == 0 ? applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString() : context.getString(stringId);
}
```

**Edit**

In light of the comment from Snicolas, I've modified the above so that it doesn't try to resolve the id if it is 0. Instead it uses, `nonLocalizedLabel` as a backoff. No need for wrapping in try/catch.

Comment: This works fine, as long as you really use a label in `android:name`. If you hardcoded a string, then it fails.

Comment: True but the app name is typically specified via a string resource of course. A hard-wired string is flagged by lint and not advised.

Comment: Just beware that it will throw android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException if the string is not found

Comment: As advised by zenocon, better put it inside a `try ... catch`.

Comment: Do you know something about the docu of nonLocalizableLabel?: "...You probably want getApplicationLabel(ApplicationInfo)"

Comment: nonLocalizedLabel: The string provided in the AndroidManifest file, if any. You probably don't want to use this. You probably want PackageManager#getApplicationLabel https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo#nonLocalizedLabel

Comment: a/a; per the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo#nonLocalizedLabel): _"You probably don't want to use this. You probably want PackageManager#getApplicationLabel"_

Answer (score 67):

**If not mentioned in the strings.xml/hardcoded in AndroidManifest.xml for whatever reason like  android:label="MyApp"**

Java

```
public String getAppLable(Context context) {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;
    try {
        applicationInfo = context.packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0);
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "The package with the given name cannot be found on the system.");
    }
    return (applicationInfo != null ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "Unknown");
}
```

Or if you know the String resource ID then you can directly get it via

```
getString(R.string.appNameID);
```

**UPDATE**

Kotlin

```
fun getAppLable(context: Context): String? {
    var applicationInfo: ApplicationInfo? = null
    try {
        applicationInfo = context.packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.applicationInfo.packageName, 0)
    } catch (e: NameNotFoundException) {
        Log.d("TAG", "The package with the given name cannot be found on the system.")
    }
    return (if (applicationInfo != null) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) else "Unknown")
}
```

Comment: while reading App Name from string.xml, sometimes, am getting junk characters. I dont know why ..Ex: à¤¸à¥&#141;à¤&#149;à¥&#136;à¤¨à¤°

Comment: It still helps in 2023. Thanks!

Comment: why do you get application info from application info? omg... `context.packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.applicationInfo.packageName, 0)`

Answer (score 66):

## Java

```
public static String getApplicationName(Context context) {
    return context.getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();
}
```

## Kotlin (as extension)

```
fun Context.getAppName(): String = applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
```

Comment: [loadLabel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#loadLabel(android.content.pm.PackageManager)) returns a `CharSequence`.  I think you need `.toString()` on the end.

Comment: return is CharSequence or String.valueOf();

Comment: It still helps in 2023. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

From any Context use:

```
getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
```

Answer (score 10):

In Kotlin its simple:

```
val appLabel = context.applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString()
```

Comment: nonLocalizedLabel.toString()

Answer (score 8):

If you need only the application name, not the package name, then just write this code.

```
 String app_name = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
```

Answer (score 8):

In **Kotlin**, use the following codes to get Application Name:

```
        // Get App Name
        var appName: String = ""
        val applicationInfo = this.getApplicationInfo()
        val stringId = applicationInfo.labelRes
        if (stringId == 0) {
            appName = applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString()
        }
        else {
            appName = this.getString(stringId)
        }
```

Comment: nonLocalizedLabel: The string provided in the AndroidManifest file, if any. You probably don't want to use this. You probably want PackageManager#getApplicationLabel https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo#nonLocalizedLabel

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

> JAVA

```java
ApplicationInfo appInfo = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
String applicationLabel = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Get Appliction Name Using RunningAppProcessInfo  as:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
Iterator i = l.iterator();
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
while(i.hasNext()) {
  ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
  try {
    CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
    Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());
  }catch(Exception e) {
    //Name Not FOund Exception
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default you have a string resource called "app_name" generated by AndroidStudio. Why not simply use that? Or any other string resource created for this purpose. Much easier than calling several internal methods to come up with a value you have to set yourself in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys another sleek option is

`Application.Context.ApplicationInfo.NonLocalizedLabel`

verified for hard coded android label on application element.

`<application android:label="Big App"></application>`

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#nonLocalizedLabel

Answer (score 1):

The source comment added to `NonLocalizedLabel` directs us now to:

```
return context.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabelFormatted(context.getApplicationInfo());
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin**

> A simple function to get the name of the application in kotlin

```
fun getApplicationName() : String{
    var applicationName = ""
    try {
        val applicationInfo = application.applicationInfo
        val stringId = applicationInfo.labelRes
        if (stringId == 0) {
            applicationName = applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString()
        }
        else {
            applicationName = application.getString(stringId)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return applicationName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `PackageManager#getActivityInfo()` method? There will be a field that should contain the name of the application.

See the answer to a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457803/how-do-i-access-androidlabel-for-an-activity).

Answer (score 0):

If "don't have access" means you don't get the expected value... Try This:

```
String appName = getString(R.string.app_name);
```