# How to determine the real names programms

Tags: android, package

at the moment only the package names are displayed (see picture):
[image]

what I want is: SlimLauncher for example instead of com.slim.slimlauncher

The corressponding code is:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager ();
    List< ApplicationInfo > packages = pm.getInstalledApplications ( PackageManager.GET_META_DATA );

    View inflate = getLayoutInflater(). inflate(R. layout. anwendung_starten_layout, null);


    String packetName = null;

    for ( ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages ) {




        packetName = packageInfo.packageName;


        kinder.add ( packetName );
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Refer to this post:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229219/android-get-application-name-not-package-name

Answer (score 3):

Refering to [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24754352/3160089) the following should work:

```
packetName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [PackageManager.getApplicationLabel(ApplicationInfo info)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationLabel(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo)):

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager ();
List< ApplicationInfo > packages = pm.getInstalledApplications ( PackageManager.GET_META_DATA );

View inflate = getLayoutInflater(). inflate(R. layout. anwendung_starten_layout, null);

String applicationName = null;
String packetName = null;

for ( ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages ) {
    applicationName = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo);
    packetName = packageInfo.packageName;
    kinder.add ( packetName );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read PackageManager->getApplicationLabel(ApplicationInfo info) API from this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationLabel(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo)) . With your code, try this:

```
packetName = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo)
```

Regards !