# How to get Android application name that is appearing in the google default launcher, from its package name?

Tags: android

I tried getting the name of other application from its package name from the code given in

> [Android: Get application name (not package name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229219/android-get-application-name-not-package-name)

But for some application, it is giving different name. eg.

> for "Phone" app, it is giving "Google dialer"
>
> for "Play store" app, it is giving "Google play store".

I understand that "Google dialer" is the application label and hence it is giving that, but is there a way to get application name as presented in the Google default launcher. (Get "Phone" instead of "Google dialer".)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
    public static String getApplicationName(Context context) {
    int stringId = context.getApplicationInfo().labelRes;
    return context.getString(stringId);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want the app name for other apps . I think, the above code will give me the app name of the current application. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: not getting you please elaborate more about your requirement.

Comment: In android, we can get the list of all the installed application via the package manager. I want their names(of all applications). So I tried the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229219/android-get-application-name-not-package-name , but it is giving me a different name for a few apps. So I was wondering, how to get app names as appear in the google now launcher.

Comment: Please check [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android/) it will help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I am doing the exact same thing , but the code `String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(            packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();` is taking the label of the application which in case of the Phone application is "Google dialer", but I need is appName = "Phone" , so the given code is not what I am looking for.