# Add app name to request scan always available (Samsung)

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

I use the following code, to ask user for enabling scan always available

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 && !wifiManager.isScanAlwaysAvailable)
        startActivity(Intent(ACTION_REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE))
```

And it's works as it should, but on Samsung Galaxy Note 4 text in window appears as "null requests permission"

---

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

How to replace null with app name?

Comment: Please add your existing source code for getting app name.

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko I'm not getting app name, I don't know where to put it, so TouchWiz could display name instead of null. Consider, I alread have app name as constant string (it's not translatable)

Comment: Did You try ["standard"](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) approach?

Comment: You are right, but in this case You can create custom dialog with App name received like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15114434/6950238) post.

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko I can't create custom dialog. This dialog is changing private system preference.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why dont you try this instead of comparing version name try comparing the version number

```
private static final int REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE = any_number;

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18 && !wifiManager.isScanAlwaysAvailable()) {
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE, REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE));
}
```

and for the resutl use below event

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE) 
     {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) 
         {
             //User has not enabled the scan always available inform him to activate it
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: 1. I'm comparing with number, not name. 2. Code works ok, just app name appears as "null" 3. I don't need result

Comment: actually, you are right in one thing - I should use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`