# How can I print the running application name in a listview?

Tags: android

I am using the below code but this is not accurate, not showing all running application. This shows only system launcher activity

```
 final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService    (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++)
    {
        Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");

      //  tv.setText(recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString());
        tv.setText("Application executed : "
                        +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"\n");

    }
```

Any one who can genuinely help me in finding all running application without any if's and but's in answering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Get application name (not package name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229219/android-get-application-name-not-package-name)

Comment: no this is not answer