# Cannot get application name from manifest in instrumentation test

Tags: android, testing, android-manifest

My Android application is composed of several modules. In my data module, I want to get the name of the application.

So far I do it by following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15114434/948128), which returns the name of the application as declared in the application manifest:

```
class Registry {
  public Registry(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
  }
  public String getApplicationName() {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = mContext.getApplicationInfo();
    int stringId = applicationInfo.labelRes;
    return stringId == 0 ? applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString() : context.getString(stringId);
  }
  private Context mContext;
}
```

This works fine when running my application: `applicationInfo.labelRes` returns a string ID, which is then translated to a string.

But the behavior is not the same in my instrumentation test: `applicationInfo.labelRes` returns 0; this leads to a `NullPointerException`, because `applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel` is null.

My test is the following:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class RegistryTest {

  @Test
  public void testGetApplicationName() {
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    Registry registry = new Registry(context);
    String applicationName = registry.getApplicationName();
    assertEquals("Foo", applicationName);
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the test is not configured to use the application manifest. What are the options so I can have the appropriate application name configured in my test?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc for `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()`

> Return the Context of this instrumentation's package

So, it's a context of your test app. If you check `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`

> Return a Context for the target application being instrumented

So, you must use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` as it represents a context of the app.

**EDIT:**

As discussed, if you have modules A and B while B depends on A then you can'r get an app name for A via instrumented test in B as the final APK merges manifests from both modules into a single one and so overwrites the name from A.