# How to get android:name from <application>

Tags: java, android

How I can dynamically get android:name from `<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:name="here custom path to java file from patch"
android:debuggable="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:resizeableActivity="true">`(in manifest) using Java?

Comment: Application his name gets from strings.xml resource file, so you can simply get it using `getString(R.string.app_name)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Get application name (not package name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229219/android-get-application-name-not-package-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the app name like this:-

```
 String appName =  getApplication().getApplicationInfo().name;
```

Comment: Thanks @Thunder for simplifying it

Comment: simple and straight solution , +1 from my side.