# Subclassing to flag another apps current view

Tags: java, android, subclassing

My understanding is that the view of another activity cannot be returned. To flag when com.android.settings > Bluetooth is the current view, am I on the right track with the code below?

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(30); 
ComponentName componentInfo = null;
String componentInfo_getPackageName;

for(int i = 0;i<taskInfo.size();i++)
{
  componentInfo = taskInfo.get(i).topActivity;
  componentInfo_getPackageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();

  if (componentInfo_getPackageName.contains("settings")){
    Class<Object> clazz = null;
    componentInfo.getClass().asSubclass(clazz);
  }   
}
```

Comment: componentInfo is an instance of `ComponentName`, and an `Activity` is *never* a `ComponentName`. Also, you're passing `null` to `asSubclass()`, which probably throws a `NullPointerException`. The questions really are, what are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: Thank you. My objective is to display a warning, when children are about to change Blue Tooth settings for example, while not interrupting changes to Date Time settings and the like.

Comment: Considering that normal, Android won't allow you to access another process directly, looking through the ActivityInfo would be the best you can do.

Comment: If I change the code above to:

if (componentInfo.toString().toLowerCase().contains("subsettings")){

}

If http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457803/how-do-i-access-androidlabel-for-an-activity is correct, how do I retrieve the ComponentName ?

Comment: Your `componentInfo` variable is a `ComponentName`,so it is alrady retrieved (you really *should* rename your variables because `ComponentInfo` is another class, making your current name choice misleading.

Comment: Am I on the right track with code below? If so, please direct me to an example for loadXmlMetaData .

if (componentName.toString().toLowerCase().contains("subsettings")){

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
     
     try {
  ActivityInfo ai = pm.getActivityInfo(componentName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES|PackageManager.GET_META_DATA|PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS);

  XmlResourceParser xml = ai.loadXmlMetaData(pm, componentName.toString());