# Android/Xamarin: How to get the label value of current activity?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I have this attribute on one of my activities in my Xamarin project and I want to get the value of Label, which is "Requirements". How do I do that?

```
[Activity(Label = "Requirements", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
```

Comment: This [article on Xamarin Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/69571) might help you

Answer (score 1):

So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457803/how-do-i-access-androidlabel-for-an-activity) stackoverflow question shows how to do it in Android native. In C# for Xamarin you can do it like this:

```
var component = new ComponentName(this, Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
var activityInfo = PackageManager.GetActivityInfo(component, 0);
var label = activityInfo.NonLocalizedLabel;
```